# Gradient Grid View With SQL and Asp.net Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I am trying to do a gradient color in asp.net below is my code behind.  When I'm debugging in google chrome the result I get is this:  background: linear-gradient(red, 'Color [A=255, R=230, G=255, B=0]';

I'm basically trying to get a gradient style grid view while pulling a user defined color from my database.  How do I accomplish this?

```
 SqlDataAdapter grid13 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [User],Colors, [TempID] 
 FROM dbo.[Colors]", con13);
    DataTable tools13 = new DataTable();
    grid13.Fill(tools13);
    DataTable alltools13 = new DataTable();


    foreach (DataRow row in tools13.Rows)
    {
        foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
        {
            if (e.Row.Cells[1].Text == (row["User"].ToString()))
            {
                e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = 
 System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(row["Colors"].ToString());
                e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = 
 System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(row["Colors"].ToString());
                e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = 
 System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(row["Colors"].ToString());
                e.Row.Cells[3].BackColor = 
 System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(row["Colors"].ToString());
               e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes.Add("style", "background: linear-
 gradient(red, 
 '"+System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(row["Colors"].ToString())+"'");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gradient is not supported by all browsers, so you should be careful about this.

In my example, I write a CSS class for each item. It is possible for you to turn this into a C # class and write methods to identify identical objects and avoid identical CSS classes, but it will not be the focus here.

**TableDAO (what?)**

It is better to work with List <> than with DataTable. But you use DataTable in the question, so I did a GoHorse here just to keep consistency with your question OK?

```
public class TableDAO
{
    public DataTable GetClients()
    {
        var clientTable = new DataTable("tblClients");
        clientTable.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
        clientTable.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
        clientTable.Columns.Add("gradientParams", typeof(string));
        clientTable.Columns.Add("gradClass", typeof(string));

        var row = clientTable.NewRow();
        row[0] = 1;
        row[1] = "Kakaroto";
        row[2] = "left,red,orange,yellow,green,blue,indigo,violet";
        row[3] = "grad1";
        clientTable.Rows.Add(row);

        row = clientTable.NewRow();
        row[0] = 2;
        row[1] = "Vegeta";
        row[2] = "right,rgba(255,0,0,0),rgba(255,0,0,1)";
        row[3] = "grad2";
        clientTable.Rows.Add(row);

        row = clientTable.NewRow();
        row[0] = 3;
        row[1] = "Broly";
        row[2] = "-90deg, red, yellow";
        row[3] = "grad3";
        clientTable.Rows.Add(row);

        return clientTable;
    }
}
```

**Aspx.cs (Code Behind)**

```
using TableDAO = MyApplication.DAO.TableDAO;
public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected string TableGradientCss { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindClients();
    }

    public void BindClients()
    {
        var dao = new TableDAO();
        var clientTable = dao.GetClients();
        gvDados.DataSource = clientTable;
        gvDados.DataBind();

        ExtractClientsGradientCss(clientTable);
    }

    protected void gvDados_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        var label = e.Row.FindControl("gradClass") as Label;
        if (label != null)
        {
            e.Row.CssClass = label.Text;
        }
    }

    private void ExtractClientsGradientCss(DataTable clients)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(DataRow row in clients.Rows)
        {
            sb.Append(
                GetGradientCss(
                    row["gradClass"].ToString(),
                    row["gradientParams"].ToString()));
        }
        TableGradientCss = sb.ToString();
    }

    private string GetGradientCss(string className, string gradientParams)
    {
        var css = @"
        .{0} {{
            background: white;                          /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient({1});   /*Safari 5.1-6*/
            background: -o-linear-gradient({1});        /*Opera 11.1-12*/
            background: -moz-linear-gradient({1});      /*Fx 3.6-15*/
            background: linear-gradient({1});           /*Standard*/
        }} ";
        return string.Format(css, className, gradientParams);
    }
}
```

**Aspx (Designer View)**

```
// some code
<style>
    <%= TableGradientCss %>
</style>
// more code
<asp:GridView ID="gvDados" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    OnRowDataBound="gvDados_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Código">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("id") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nome">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("name") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="gradClass" runat="server"
                    Text='<%# Eval("gradClass") %>'>
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you that helped a ton!  Sorry for the late reply.  I'm a bit of a beginner so I was using what I thought would be "easiest".  I am going to give the list a try and see where that takes me...